# Passing NULL to a function designed to build a MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Language: PHP and MySQL

I have some rows in a database that have a column with a value of NULL. I have a function that builds the query when it receive a $params array. Here's the relevant piece of code in that function (to build the WHERE clause):

```
    if (isset($params['where'])) {
        $query .= "WHERE ";
        $count = count($params['where']);
        foreach ($params['where'] as $key => $value) {
            $count--;
            if ($count) {
                $query .= "`$key` ".$value['sign']." '".$value['text']."' AND ";
            } else {
               $query .= "`$key` ".$value['sign']." '".$value['text']."' ";
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I set $value['text'] to null, here's the result:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` WHERE `committed` IS '' LIMIT 100
```

If I set it to $value['text'] = 'NULL', then I get the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` WHERE `committed` IS 'NULL' LIMIT 100
```

Which of course produces nothing. Any ideas?

## ANSWER

```
    if (isset($params['where'])) {
        $where_segment = array ();
        foreach ($params['where'] as $key => $value) {
            if (is_null($value['text'])) {
                $where_segment[] = "`".$key."`"." IS NULL";
            } else {
                $where_segment[] = "`$key` ".$value['sign']." '".$value['text']."' ";
            }
        }
        $query .= " WHERE ".implode('AND', $where_segment);
    }
```

Comment: I hope your code is sql injection aware

Comment: sql injection is not the issue I'm trying to address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $string_array = array();

    foreach($params['where'] as $field => $value) {

        if(is_null($value)) {
            $string_array[] = "`$field` IS NULL";
        }
        else {
            $string_array[] = "`$field`='$value'";
        }

    }

 $where_string = "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $string_array);


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` $where_string";
```

Notice that if the $value is NULL I omit the '' marks around the NULL phrase.

Comment: You cannot use '=' with NULL, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html You have to use "IS". Otherwise, your answer gave me an idea on how to solve the problem, I will test it first.

Comment: I did not know that. I changed the '=' sign to 'IS', that will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query.

SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` WHERE `committed` IS NULL LIMIT 100.

Remove the single quotes.

Comment: Yes, but this does not address my question

Comment: yes, when you assign $value['text'] to null, it does not keep the text null in $value['text']. It means empty. so, you are getting WHERE `committed` IS ''. Better you can use string replacement. Convert 'NULL' to NULL in query string.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you without single quotes

```
 SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` WHERE `committed` IS NULL LIMIT 100
```

you could set your variable like that to null

```
 $value['text'] = NULL;
```

and then in your query

```
 SELECT * FROM `db_profiles` WHERE `committed` IS $value['text'] LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not my question'

Comment: No, you should read the question again. I posted an answer and one of the other responders posted an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

When populating the values to the query, you'll need an explicit check for something like:

```
if(is_null($value)) {
    $query . ' WHERE something IS NULL';
} else {
    $query . ' WHERE something \'' . $value . '\'';
}
```

Note that when you are new to MySQL and PHP you should start to use prepared statements as soon as possible. They are most secure against SQL injection vulnerabilities and easy to use. You can start [here](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to learn to use them.